# Implicit flow & identity Server 3: Is it possible to grant a JavaScript client an access token without having the user log in?

Tags: javascript, access-token, implicit, identityserver3

I have a public API that i want to secure using Identity Server 3.

I have an MVC application and a Javascript application and I want to ensure that only these clients can access the API regardless of Users / Resource Owners being logged in or identified.  This is easy to do using the client credentials flow in the MVC app but does not seem possible using the implicit flow. (http://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2/grants/implicit.html) <- relies on the resource owner being identified.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  I'm using the oidc-token-manager.

Thanks much.

M.

Comment: In MVC, just add the `[Anonymous]` attribute to a route so that anyone can access it

Comment: That's the problem though. I don't want everyone to access it, just Authorized Clients.  I don't care if the user is anonymous, but i don't want the calling application to be anonymous.

Comment: You are talking about service to service flow right. For that, I remember we made the service do a HttpRequest to the ID server for a token

Comment: Not in this case.  I'm talking about the JavaScript client to Api scenario.  The service to service one is easy to do using the client credentials flow (calling Id Server for a token using a shared secret).  the implicit flow relies on a redirect for client validation.  It also seems like it needs the User to be signed in as well... that's the problem i'm having. i don't want to sign in a user, i just dont' want anyone hooking up a JS app to my API unless i explicitly allow their client app. I'm very selfish. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only securely rely on the identity of the client, if the client is "confidential". That means the client can securely store its client secret.

This is true for server-based applications (e.g. client creds flow server to server, or a code based flow invoked by a server).

This is not possible for clients that are outside of your "control" like SPAs or desktop/mobile apps.

IdentityServer always includes a `client_id` claim - but the above caveat applies.